# android dynamically created layouts overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

I want to create a relative layout inside a linear layout dynamically.This relative layout contains a text view and button which are also created in dynamic method.The alignment of text view and button not work properly.The code which i have tried is given below.

```
final LinearLayout lab_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_list_layout);
lab_linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
for (int i = 0; i < Size_contact; i++) 
 {
   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new   
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

   final TextView Questions_value = new   
   android.widget.TextView(getApplicationContext());
   Questions_value.setText(contact_name.get(i));
   Questions_value.setTextSize(18);
   Questions_value.setId(i);
   layout.addView(Questions_value);

   Button myButton = new Button(this);
   myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close);
   myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20,20));
   layout.addView(myButton);

   lab_linear.addView(layout);
   }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your desired layout?

Comment: You are not specific to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Give layout parems for `RelativeLayout` individually to  `TextView` and `Button` and also add `addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); or addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);` for that views

Or add the below in for `Button`

`lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, Questions_value.getId());`

```
for (int i = 0; i < Size_contact; i++) 
 {
   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new   
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

   final TextView Questions_value = new   
   android.widget.TextView(getApplicationContext());
   Questions_value.setText(contact_name.get(i));
   Questions_value.setTextSize(18);
   Questions_value.setId(i);
   layout.addView(Questions_value,lp);

   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
   //Or below remove above code and uncomment the below code
   //lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, Questions_value.getId());
   Button myButton = new Button(this);
   myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close);
   myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20,20));
   layout.addView(myButton,lp1);

   lab_linear.addView(layout);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using LinearLayouts instead of RelativeLayouts in your loop? That way, you won't have the overlap problem.